# Acumatica REST API Returns error when calling and action

Tags: acumatica

I have made an action and it works good on the Acaumatica page. The action calls another API connection. When I try to call the action on the API WebEndpoint I'm getting an error.

This is the Action:

```
rotected virtual void giftCardDoPayment()
    {
        GiftCardPayment currentGCP = GiftCardPaymentView.SelectSingle();
        var client = CreateClient();
        var request = new GiftCardTransCreate
        {
            ProgramId = 33,
            Code = currentGCP.GiftCardNumber,
            Type = OnLoyalty.GiftCardTransType.ToPurchase,
            Amount = currentGCP.Amount,
            RegisterId = "POSRegister",
            RefNo = currentGCP.RefNo,
        };
        var response = client.Post(request);
        var paymentResults = PXCache<GiftCardPayment>.CreateCopy(GiftCardPaymentView.Current);
        paymentResults.TransactionID = response.TransactionId;
        paymentResults.CustomerCardNumber = response.Result.CustomerCardNumber;
        paymentResults.CustomerFullName = response.Result.CustomerFullName;
        paymentResults.Type = response.Result.Type;
        paymentResults.Status = response.Result.Status;
        paymentResults.Balance = response.Result.Balance;
        paymentResults.PendingAmount = response.Result.PendingAmount;
        paymentResults.ExpiresOn = response.Result.ExpiresOn;
        GiftCardPaymentView.Update(paymentResults); }
```

And this is my Call on Postman:

```
{
"entity" : {  
    "Amount": { "value": -18.00 },
    "GiftCardNumber": { "value": "7AE9ABBE-E25E-40E3-8ED9-BDEE23AAEEED" },
    "ReferenceNumber": { "value": "1234" } 
}
```

}

And the response I'm getting:

```
{
"message": "An error has occurred.",
"exceptionMessage": "Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: source",
"exceptionType": "System.ArgumentNullException",
"stackTrace": "   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Select[TSource,TResult](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 selector)\r\n   at PX.Api.ContractBased.EntityExportContextBuilder.BuildSearchCommands(EntityDescriptor descriptor, Boolean primaryViewOnly) in F:\\Bld\\AC-FULL61U12-JOB1\\sources\\NetTools\\PX.Api.ContractBased\\EntityExportContextBuilder.cs:line 1678\r\n   at PX.Api.ContractBased.EntityExportContextBuilder.<BuildUpdatePositioningCommands>d__58.MoveNext() in F:\\Bld\\AC-FULL61U12-JOB1\\sources\\NetTools\\PX.Api.ContractBased\\EntityExportContextBuilder.cs:line 1398\r\n   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.InsertRange(Int32 index, IEnumerable`1 collection)\r\n   at PX.Api.ContractBased.EntityExportContextBuilder.BuildContextForInvoke(EntityDescriptor entityDescriptor, ActionImpl action, Boolean newEntity) in F:\\Bld\\AC-FULL61U12-JOB1\\sources\\NetTools\\PX.Api.ContractBased\\EntityExportContextBuilder.cs:line 1823\r\n   at PX.Api.ContractBased.EntityService.Invoke(ISystemContract systemContract, String version, String name, EntityImpl entity, ActionImpl action, CbOperationContext operationContext) in F:\\Bld\\AC-FULL61U12-JOB1\\sources\\NetTools\\PX.Api.ContractBased\\EntityService.cs:line 746\r\n   at PX.Api.ContractBased.Soap.EntityGateBase.InvokeImpl(EntityImpl entity, ActionImpl action) in F:\\Bld\\AC-FULL61U12-JOB1\\sources\\NetTools\\PX.Api.ContractBased\\Soap\\EntityGateBase.cs:line 145\r\n   at PX.Api.ContractBased.Soap.EntityGateV2.PX.Api.ContractBased.IRestGate.Invoke(EntityImpl entity, ActionImpl action) in F:\\Bld\\AC-FULL61U12-JOB1\\sources\\NetTools\\PX.Api.ContractBased\\Soap\\EntityGateV2.cs:line 358\r\n   at PX.Api.ContractBased.WebApi.Controllers.RestSystemContract2Controller.InvokeAction(EntityEndpoint endpoint, String objectName, String actionName, ActionInvocation invocation) in F:\\Bld\\AC-FULL61U12-JOB1\\sources\\NetTools\\PX.Api.ContractBased\\WebApi\\Controllers\\RestSystemContract2Controller.cs:line 86\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()"}
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your Acumatica code as you make the endpoint call?

Comment: Could you give us more information on the API call? like the url you are posting your call to, the way the endpoint is created which screen you are targetting?

Comment: I tried to debug but I'm realizing that the API its not hitting my action. I'm following the guidelines for executing an action on the URL entity/<Endpoint name>/6.00.001/GiftCardPayment/giftCardDoPayment.  I'm targeting a custom screen.

Comment: Does your custom screen have any keys on its primary view?

Comment: No, I don't have any keys. All my fields on my DAC are unbound fields and I don't have a DB for this.

Comment: I used a Put request for the action, and made sure my fields were populated correctly. That worked thanks!